# How to pass a dynamic ID to a function in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Update:

in my code-behind code i have public varaible and assing like this

```
public string Id { get { return Request.QueryString["id"].ToString(); } }`
```

and in .aspx page i am trying to access

```
$(this).attr("EmployeeId", Id);
```

getting the error The name

```
'Id' does not exist in the current context
```

**end update**

i have two aspx pages:

```
1) employee.aspx
2) employee_detail.aspx
```

how to pass an dynamic id from one page to another page

the below code is in the `employee.aspx` page

```
//more code here..
//but to relvant to my question is here...

var submitButton = function()  {             
  //more code here...         
  if(employeeId != ""){   //redirecting here...
    window.location.href = "employee_detail.aspx"; 
 }    
}
```

so in `employee_detail.aspx` page i have a jquery function, currently i am hardcoding the id 
something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

$(document).ready(function () { 

 var id = 'A42345'; //hardcoded.... 

$(this).attr("EmployeeId", id);  

</script>
```

so my question is, i am looking a way to pass an id from `employee.aspx` and receive in `employee_detail.aspx`

i thought of doing this but for security reason i dont want to expose the id in the url:

```
window.location.href = "mypage.aspx?id = " + id;
```

Comment: You can create hidden input field with EmployeeId value. Then ID will be submited together with form values.

Comment: If the inclusion of the ID in the URL querystring warrants a security concern, you really shouldn't be passing it around on the client side (e.g: via Javascript) at all, as ANY data processed by Javascript is accessible and malleable by the client.

Answer (score 0):

You should seriously look into implementing sessions and storing the user ID in a session variable instead of passing it around manually like this. Read this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx

But if you insist, you can use jQuery to POST the data to the second page, instead of using GET and then on the server (ASP) side, echo the POST variable value into Javascript.

Comment: Problem with session is that you cannot have the same page with different query in tow window. Session with the same name will re-write the session content.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine your dynamic code in javascript like (And the order should be like this) please note that im using ASP classic.

```
<% 
Dim ID
ID = Request.QueryString("id") 'Or any other request
%>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
var id = '<%=id%>'//OR any dynamic request
$(this).attr("EmployeeId", id); 
</script>
```

Comment: CS1955: Non-invocable member 'System.Web.HttpRequest.QueryString' cannot be used like a method.

Comment: If you have your javascript code in .js file it will not work this way, but if you have your code in dynamic page like .asp, .php, etc. it will work. Even you can use Record Sets like var id = <%=rs("name")%>.

Comment: You should have your js code after your dynamic code. Basically you should have your ID in dynamic and then invoke it in javascript. Look at the edit I made in my answer.

Comment: still getting the same erro `<%  string _id = Request.QueryString("id"); %>`

Comment: Non-invocable member 'System.Web.HttpRequest.QueryString' cannot be used like a method.

Comment: suppose to be bracket, Request.QueryString["id"];, its working now but the question still i have is showing the id in my browser, any thoughts on this?

Comment: What do you mean showing in browser? Are you talking about code view in javascript code? Since javascript is a client side  and open source programing it might not be a right solution for you because your id/data will show up in code view of the page but if you want to not show up in query string you always have option to use "ajax post" and treat it as a post form. Its exactly like you've submitted a form but it just passed the id to next page. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "employee_detail.aspx",
            dataType: "json",
            data: { id: 1 }, // or the string: 'id=1'
            complete:
            function () {
                window.location = "employee_detail.aspx";
            }

    });
```

From http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: i am not posting the page, and i am simply redirecting to a page and in the receiving end i am looking a way to get the value that i am passing from.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax with a webmethod in your server code. In the web method you can access Sessions with the HttpContext.Current

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "mypage.aspx/ServerMethodName",    
    data: '{"id":"' + $("#divID").text() + '"}',        
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (returnValueFromServerMethod) {
        if(returnValueFromServerMethod.d != "")
            //do something great

    }
});

[WebMethod]
public static string ServerMethodName(string id)
{
    HttpContext.Current.Session["ID"] = id;            
}
```

You will need to add a in your page.aspx to enable page methods.

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true">                    
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

You can replace the page method stuff with a service .svc which would be cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you are simply trying to pass a variable, cookies will do the job.  Obviously this isn't a secure means of storing data but provides an invisible layer to the average user.

https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

This plugin is very small and simple...

To set a cookie on the first page:

```
$.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value');
```

or

```
$.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value', { expires: 7 });
```

And to get the value on the next page:

```
$.cookie('the_cookie');
```

Answer (score 0):

An option I've enjoyed using in the past involves submitting a form to the page being loaded.  That form has an hidden field containing JSON data that the javascript wants to pass to the page.  The server then looks for the JSON data, parses it and uses the values it contains.

This is somewhat similar to ASP's viewstate and/or session, but works without needing viewstate or session turned on.